# Source a bunch of files in R script in a nice way

Tags: r

I have a script, let say `main.R`. I have a dozen of function files that I source in the main script. 
It looks like:

```
source('doThis.R')
source('doThat.R')
source('coolFun.R')
source('anotherFun.R')
```

...and so on.
It is not a big problem but I would get rid of it. Should I just make a function `sourceAll.R` to source everything else and source it in my `main.R`? Or there are other ways to deal with functions?

Comment: I would create a package instead of `source`ing multiple files.  Please note that when you have lots of files and working on a prod env, this can create some issues esp with the path

Comment: Thank you @akrun. I thought about making a package but my boss thinks we don't need it and he has his reasons for that. People who use that script just pull it with git so the folder structure stays the same. Anyway, I got no problem with sourcing so far. I will keep in mind what you said.

Comment: You can make a function and map your names to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Occassionally, I find it less cumbersome to source some R files the sloppy way instead of creating a properly documented and maintained package (although the latter may pay off, especially when shared by many users).

This is what I have done in these cases:

```
file_names <- c(
  "doThis.R",
  "doThat.R",
  "coolFun.R",
  "anotherFun.R"
)
lapply(file_names, source)
```

You may pass arguments to `source()` as well, e.g.,

```
lapply(file_names, source, local = TRUE)
```

If all files to source are located in one directory, you may get the file names by simply calling `list_files()`:

```
file_names <- list.files(path = "path_to_directory_of_R_files", pattern = "\\.R$")
lapply(file_names, source)
```